# Visual studio scrollbar

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

I recently upgraded VS 2005 to VS 2008. Unfortunately I have a very basic problem: In the codeview window my vertical scrollbar does not look like a normal, traditional scrollbar, but like some kind of code-preview window. It is roundabout four times wider than a normal scrollbar.
The problem is that my ReSharper (4.1) seems not to work with this scrollbar. As soon as I enable ReSharper the scrollbar freezes. Switching the whole vertial scrollbar off is not an option, too, since I am used to have a scrollbar :/
I would really like to get rid of this new-style scrollbar and turn it back to a normal one.
Has anyone had similar problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the [RockScroll](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx) add-in? If so, disable it.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's it - I never heard of rockscroll before. ReSharper is more important to me. As long as rockscroll and ReSharper are not working together I will disable rockscroll.

Answer (score 0):

You have RockScroll installed. - try updating RockScroll

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingRockScroll.aspx

if not just remove it

Scott does note that RockScroll is a Works on my Machine release!

[bah beaten to it!]